# Curved scrollbar in ScrollView on Android Wear 2.0

Tags: scrollview, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

Is it possible to have a curved scrollbar like on WearableRecyclerView on ScrollView? How is it done?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/lists.html#creating) is a reference to get you started.

> To create a curved layout for scrollable items in your wearable app:
>
> - Use [`WearableRecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wear/widget/WearableRecyclerView.html) as your main container in the relevant XML layout.
> - Set the [`setEdgeItemsCenteringEnabled(boolean)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wear/widget/WearableRecyclerView.html#setEdgeItemsCenteringEnabled(boolean)) method to true. This will align the first and last items on the list vertically
>     centered on the screen.
> - Use the `WearableRecyclerView.setLayoutManager()` method to set layout of the items on the screen.

If you explore the document, you will be able to get in touch with the code snippet for customization of the scrolling.

For [Circular Scrolling Gesture](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/lists.html#adding):

> By default, circular scrolling is disabled in the
>   [`WearableRecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wear/widget/WearableRecyclerView.html). If you want to enable a circular
>   scrolling gesture in your child view, use the `WearableRecyclerView`’s
>   [`setCircularScrollingGestureEnabled()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wear/widget/WearableRecyclerView.html#setCircularScrollingGestureEnabled(boolean)) method.

Comment: You can't use a XML layout file in WearableRecyclerView and that's why I wanted to use ScrollView.